# Oracle Debugging won't work SQL developer 4.2.0.17

Tags: debugging, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have debugging privs and compiled my packages and package bodies for debug. When I try to launch the debugger, I get the following.

```
Executing PL/SQL: ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_DEBUG=TRUE
Executing PL/SQL: CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CONNECT_TCP( 'XX.XX.XX.XXX', 'YYYYY' )
ORA-30683: failure establishing connection to debugger
ORA-12535: TNS:operation timed out
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP", line 68
ORA-06512: at line 1
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database ZZZ
```

I tried setting DatabaseDebuggerDisableJDWP=true in my ide.properites file (all of them), and it didn't help.

Comment: Sounds like your hidden IP address and port are wrong, or there is a firewall in the way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this resolve:

Tools -> Preferences -> Debugger - set the **Prompt for debugger host for database debugging.**

Set your machine ip address when it prompt and i think it will be work.

Comment: Thank you.  I had already done that.  It looks like I put "DatabaseDebuggerDisableJDWP=true" too far down in the script.  
When put "DatabaseDebuggerDisableJDWP=true"  on the first line, it worked.  I also had to make the changes and then go in and out of SQL developer several times before the changes stuck.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I put DatabaseDebuggerDisableJDWP=true too far down in ide.properties file.
When put DatabaseDebuggerDisableJDWP=true  on the first line, it worked.  I also had to make the changes and go in and out of Sql developer several times before the changes stuck.